# What are the parameters I should consider while selecting a Memory IC?

Tags: memory

I have a Microcontroller which needs to be connected to a memory using SPI Interface. What are the major parameters that I have to consider while choosing a Flash IC?

Comment: Why don't you just browse a bunch of SPI memory ICs and look at what parameters they provide? We can't tell you which parameters you should consider without knowing what you need, but you can't tell us what you need because you don't know what parameters there are. Basic parameters are voltage, speed, volatility, and size but then there's stuff like the actual SPI commands available.

Comment: Well make sure that the word size (organization), the SPI mode (e.g. some ICs use microwire which is a subset of SPI) and the required instruction set is the same for both sides. Furthermore it is good thing if the total mem size is big enough and the required voltage(s) are the same.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory size you need, supply voltage the chip works with and maybe throughput (not the speed of SPI bus itself  but average write speed).